# Replace a text with regular expression in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to replace all the url's which are starting with something like **www.sitename.com/xxx/xxx.html** and the last part of the string is different on each url. Is there any formula in notepad++ which replace the whole string with `"#"` or any custom character ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press Ctrl+H to bring up the replace window. Enter this in the `Find what:` section:

```
www\.sitename\.com(/\w+)*\.?\w*
```

and anything you want (#) in the `Replace with:`. Make sure that `Search Mode` is on `Regulare Expression` and the hit the `Find next`, `Replace` or `Replace All`

This will replace all the URLs beginning with `www.sitename.com` and ending with and extension (.html, .jpg, ...)

Answer (score 3):

Bring on the `Find and Replace` dialog, select `Replace` (`Ctrl+H`)

Search mode: `Regular expression`

Find what: `www\.sitename\.com/\w+/\w+\.html`

Replace with: `#` (or anything you wish)

This will replace URLs of the type you've provided in question (`www.sitename.com/xxx/xxx.html`)